# How to assign a task to a queue

Tags: queue

Is it possible to assign a task to a queue. When I tried it manually I am only able to select users no drop-down for changing user to queue. Can any one suggest me is their any other way or do I am missing out anything? Or the queue can only be assign to case and lead only?

Comment: Depending on your requirements there are ways to give this functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not (yet) possible to assign tasks to queues. You can vote on [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=087300000007HC0AAM).

Answer (score 1):

Now available in Lightning with [Spring '20](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_sales_productivity_activities_task_queues.htm) (but not Classic). A valid reason to switch